Error (-32002): Error processing Instruction 2: Provided owner is not allowed
Can anyone tell me what the error might be?
{accounts: null, err: {InstructionError: [2, IllegalOwner]}, innerInstructions: null, logs: [Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1], Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success, Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1], Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success, Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1], Program log: Create, Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 3610 of 101037 compute units, Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: Provided owner is not allowed], returnData: null, unitsConsumed: 3910}

The exchange program code itself
Future<void> _buyToken(
      Ed25519HDKeyPair wallet, PoolInfo poolInfo, double amountIn) async {
    Ed25519HDPublicKey? _wSolAssociatedToken;
    var _amountIn = amountIn.toDecimal(BigInt.from(9));
    final inputToken = Ed25519HDPublicKey.fromBase58(wSolAddress);

    try {
      _wSolAssociatedToken = await findAssociatedTokenAddress(
          owner: wallet.publicKey, mint: inputToken);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("signature:: error: $e");
    }

    if (_wSolAssociatedToken == null) return;

    Ed25519HDPublicKey? _outputAssociatedToken;

    Ed25519HDPublicKey? _outputToken =
        poolInfo.baseMint.toBase58() == wSolAddress
            ? poolInfo.quoteMint
            : poolInfo.baseMint;

    try {
      _outputAssociatedToken = await findAssociatedTokenAddress(
          owner: wallet.publicKey, mint: _outputToken);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("signature:: error: $e");
    }

    if (_outputAssociatedToken == null) return;

    final instruction = makeSwapFixedInInstruction(
      userKeys: UserKeys(
          owner: wallet.publicKey,
          tokenAccountIn: _wSolAssociatedToken,
          tokenAccountOut: _outputAssociatedToken),
      amountIn: _amountIn,
      poolInfo: poolInfo,
    );

 final program1 =
        ComputeBudgetInstruction.setComputeUnitLimit(units: 101337);
   
 final program2 =
        ComputeBudgetInstruction.setComputeUnitPrice(microLamports: 421197);
   
 final program3 = AssociatedTokenAccountInstruction.createAccount(
        funder: wallet.publicKey,
        address: _wSolAssociatedToken,
        owner: wallet.publicKey,
        mint: inputToken);

    final program4 = SystemInstruction.transfer(
        fundingAccount: wallet.publicKey,
        recipientAccount: _wSolAssociatedToken,
        lamports: _amountIn.toInt());

    final program5 =
        TokenInstruction.syncNative(nativeTokenAccount: _wSolAssociatedToken);

    final program6 = AssociatedTokenAccountInstruction.createAccount(
        funder: wallet.publicKey,
        address: _outputAssociatedToken,
        owner: wallet.publicKey,
        mint: _outputToken);

    final program7 = instruction;

    ///закрываем счёт V
    final program8 = TokenInstruction.closeAccount(
        accountToClose: _wSolAssociatedToken,
        destination: wallet.publicKey,
        owner: wallet.publicKey);

    final message = Message(instructions: [
      program1,
      program2,
      program3,
      program4,
      program5,
      program6,
      program7,
      program8
    ]);

    try {
      var signature = await _solanaClient.rpcClient.signAndSendTransaction(
          message, [wallet], commitment: Commitment.confirmed,
          onSigned: (signature) {
        debugPrint("signature::  signature ${base58encode(signature.bytes)}");
        _logs.add("signature: ${base58encode(signature.bytes)}");
        // _getTransaction(signature.toBase58());
      });
      _solanaClient.waitForSignatureStatus(signature,
          status: Commitment.confirmed,
          pingInterval: const Duration(seconds: 1));
    } catch (e) {
      _tradeDeal = null;
      debugPrint("signature:: error $e");
    }
  }


The create ATA instruction expects the owner to be the "owner account". It doesn't represent the account authority as you've used it above
Use either the SPL Tokens program id or SPL Token - 22 program id
final program3 = AssociatedTokenAccountInstruction.createAccount(
        funder: wallet.publicKey,
        address: _wSolAssociatedToken,
        owner: TOKEN_PROGRAM-ID,
        mint: inputToken);
);

TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA'
TOKEN_22_PROGRAM_ID = 'TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb'
By clarifying that you are using wrapped SOL, here's how you can make the transfer using the system program.
  // remember to create ATA first
  let ata = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    NATIVE_MINT, // mint
    recipinentPublicKey, // 
  );
 
  let amount = 1 * 1e9; /* Wrapped SOL's decimals is 9 */
 
  let tx = new Transaction().add(
    // trasnfer SOL
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: alice.publicKey,
      toPubkey: ata,
      lamports: amount,
    }),

    // sync wrapped SOL balance
    createSyncNativeInstruction(ata),


I tried to do as you wrote. Now another error appears. error jsonrpc-2.0 error (-32002): Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address

which instruction is causing this? Did you also update the program6 instruction with the correct programId?

Yes? I update program 3 and program 6. ...Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1], Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success, Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1], Program log: Create, Program log: Error: Associated address does not match seed derivation, Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 3641 of 101037 compute units, Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address], returnData: null, unitsConsumed: 3941}

what's the mint address? are you by chance using wrapped SOL?

wSolAddress = "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112";

The most interesting thing is that it worked and then at some point an error began to appear

Check this guide https://solana.com/developers/cookbook/tokens/manage-wrapped-sol
